# How to filter list by comma and append the value to dynamic variable in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that i retrieve from database and it has two value:

```
list = [('xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}', ' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2" || "testNested"}', '{ "subjectP1": "WorkedDynamicWord","wordP1": "hi1","subjectP2": "WorkedDynamicWord2", "wordP2": "Dynamic word"}'), ('xxx@yahoo.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject"}', '{ "condition1": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "haha"}', None)]
```

As you can see, the two different value is differentiate with the comma at `),`. So how can i seperate these two value and insert to a variable for each list value?

For example (expected output):

```
variableA =  ('xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}', ' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2" || "testNested"}', '{ "subjectP1": "WorkedDynamicWord","wordP1": "hi1","subjectP2": "WorkedDynamicWord2", "wordP2": "Dynamic word"}')

variableB = ('xxx@yahoo.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject"}', '{ "condition1": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "haha"}', None)
```

The variable will be add dynamically if the database has third value. For example, variableC will store the third value and variableD will be generate if there is fourth value.

Comment: Can you explain why you need dynamic variable names and cannot work with a list or dictionary? Maybe there is an alternative way of doing what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variables as such

```
data = [('xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}', ' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2" || "testNested"}', '{ "subjectP1": "WorkedDynamicWord","wordP1": "hi1","subjectP2": "WorkedDynamicWord2", "wordP2": "Dynamic word"}'), ('xxx@yahoo.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject"}', '{ "condition1": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "haha"}', None)]

for i,l in enumerate(data):
    vars()[f'variable{i + 1}'] = l

print(variable1, variable2)
```

Comment: Ok, you can do that, but that's a really bad idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: Thanks for the respond, if i want get index for all the variable value , how can i do it? For example: variable*[0]. How can i define all variable1,2,3 without state specifically a variable name?

Answer (score 1):

Python’s globals() function returns a dictionary containing the current global symbol table, so you can add your variables with custom names:

```
data = [('xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}', ' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2" || "testNested"}', '{ "subjectP1": "WorkedDynamicWord","wordP1": "hi1","subjectP2": "WorkedDynamicWord2", "wordP2": "Dynamic word"}'), ('xxx@yahoo.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject"}', '{ "condition1": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "haha"}', None)]

for iVariable, variable in enumerate(data):
    globals()["variable"+str(iVariable+1)] = variable
    
print("Variable 1 : ", variable1)
print("Variable 2 : ",variable2)
```

The output is:

```
Variable 1 :  ('xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject", "header2": "Text"}', ' { "condition1": "Equal", "condition2": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2" || "testNested"}', '{ "subjectP1": "WorkedDynamicWord","wordP1": "hi1","subjectP2": "WorkedDynamicWord2", "wordP2": "Dynamic word"}')
Variable 2 :  ('xxx@yahoo.com', '111@gmail.com\n', '{ "header1": "Subject"}', '{ "condition1": "Contain"}', '{ "parameter1": "haha"}', None)
```

If you prefer to have letters (variableA, variableB, ...), replace `str(iVariable+1)` by `chr(ord('@')+iVariable+1)` that will convert the number to corresponding alphabetic character.

**Note:** creating such variables is not recommended and you may reconsider your need for it, see the following link for more details and alternatives:
[How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: That's possible, but it's a bad idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables for some reasons why and clean alternatives.

Comment: Understood, I updated the answer with a note. Still the answer is the way to address the specific OP question.